# how to display comments for posts in rails (by iteration )

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I managed to link comments to their posts in rails but the remaining thing is displaying them and here is my view(simplified) :
the thing is that iam iterating through `post.all` and each post `has_many :comments` and each comment has `comment.description` `comment.image` so how can I get to show the comment for each of the iterated posts is it by another iteration ?

_profile.html.erb :

```
    @posts.each do |x|
    <div class="eachpost-wrapper">
    <%= x.text %>
    <%= x.picture %>
          <div class="comments-for-each-post">
    <<<<<<<<< the post comments are supposed to be here <<<<<<
   </div> 
</div>
<% end %>
```

accounts controller :

```
def profile
@posts = User.find(params[:id]).posts
@comment = Comment.new
  end
```

comments controller :

```
def new

         @comment = Comment.new
       end
      def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
       @comment = @post.comments.new
       if @comment.save
              redirect_to "success/success"
       else
              redirect_to 'error/error404'
       end
```

Comment: `x.comments` should return the list of the `Comment` records associated to the `Post` --- you will want to eager load this relation to avoid N+1 queries also by doing `@posts = User.find(params[:id]).posts.includes(:comments)`

Comment: How did you manage to make it work? You had a question yesterday with a strange error that is no longer visible. I also remember posting an answer which did it solve the problem. Can’t you share he solution? Regarding your question here, yes, it’s another iteration through post.comments (I have renamed x to post to be more clear).

Comment: thanks Mryoshiji but how would I call individual comment.text will it be x.comments.text and thanks for your amazing answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is by another iteration. Something along the lines of:

```
<div class="posts-wrapper">
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post-wrapper">
      <%= post.text %>
      <%= post.picture %>
      <div class="comments-wrapper">
        <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
          <div class="comment-wrapper">
            # do stuff with comment here...
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="new-comment-wrapper">
        # put a new comment form in here...
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Keeping in mind what MrYoshiji said about eager loading...